# Can I extract the no. 2 digit from string into integer?

Tags: java

In my case ,the users can input

```
f 0 ,f 1, f 2//1 digit
p 0, p 1 ,p 2//1 digit
j 0 1, j 0 2, j 1 0....(any combination of 0,1,2) //2 digits
q ,Q //for quit
```

I use

```
      str = scanner.nextLine();//get the whole line of input
 if(str.matches("[fpjq]\\s[012]"))......//check vaild input
             char1=str .charAt(0);//get the first letter
```

Then I want to get the next digit now .

Any string method can extract the next digit from string into Int format?

However ,some bugs still exist for my method . For example , it can quit the program for QQ or qq or q+any letters

Any better methods can be provided?

## edit

for example `p 0 1`
char1=str .charAt(0);//get p
now I want to get 0 and 1 and store into int

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you want to extract from the first line, for example?

Comment: You mean `str.charAt(2);` ?

Comment: @Scary Wombat  I tried .I think it gets the ascil code ,like 48,68...

Comment: Assigning a `char` to an `int` won't convert digits... you could subtract `'0'`, I guess, if there isn't a more elegant way

Comment: @qxz or `Integer.parseInt ()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) `(...)` in your regex to extract parts of the matched data:

```
str = scanner.nextLine();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^([fpjq])(?:\\s+([012]))?(?:\\s+([012]))?$");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(str.trim());
if (matcher.find()) {
    String letter = matcher.group(1);
    String digit1 = matcher.group(2); // null if none
    String digit2 = matcher.group(3); // null if none
    // use Integer.parseInt to convert to int...
} else {
    // invalid input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split on spaces.

```
String input = "j 0 1";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");

String command = parts[0];
int arg1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
int arg2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
```

Comment: More robust would be to `.trim()` it and then split on `\s+`